# Automatically transfer HList into a Record

Tags: scala, shapeless

My goal is to automatically transfer a `HList` into a `Record` on demand.

Note that the below code is written in Scala 2.13 and uses singleton types instead of `Symbol`s.

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.record._
import shapeless.labelled._

type BestBeforeDate = Record.`"day" -> Option[Int], "month" -> Option[Int], "year" -> Int`.T

object PolyToField extends Poly1 {
   implicit def mapA[A, K]: Case.Aux[A, FieldType[K, A]] = at[A](a => field[K][A](a))
}

val x: BestBeforeDate = (None :: None :: 12 :: HNil)
   .map(PolyToField)
```

I get this error:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : None.type with shapeless.labelled.KeyTag[Nothing,None.type] :: None.type with shapeless.labelled.KeyTag[Nothing,None.type] :: Int with shapeless.labelled.KeyTag[Nothing,Int] :: shapeless.HNil
 required: emergencymanager.commons.data.package.BestBeforeDate
    (which expands to)  Option[Int] with shapeless.labelled.KeyTag[String("day"),Option[Int]] :: Option[Int] with shapeless.labelled.KeyTag[String("month"),Option[Int]] :: Int with shapeless.labelled.KeyTag[String("year"),Int] :: shapeless.HNil
```

It seems like the second type parameter of the `Poly1` function is inferred to `Nothing` instead of what I need.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Firstly,** you should specify with type ascription that `None` has type `Option[...]` (that's the reason why in Cats [there are](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/syntax/option.scala) `none[...]` and `.some`, see [also](https://blog.softwaremill.com/9-tips-about-using-cats-in-scala-you-might-want-to-know-e1bafd365f88#04e9), item 9). Or use `Option.empty[...]`.

**Secondly,** you should use [mapper with return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36515901/shapeless-map-hlist-depending-on-target-types) rather than standard [shapeless.ops.hlist.Mapper](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/ops/hlists.scala#L307-L331)

```
trait MapperWithReturnType[HF, Out <: HList] extends Serializable {
  type In <: HList
  def apply(t: In): Out
}

object MapperWithReturnType {
  type Aux[HF, Out <: HList, In0 <: HList] = 
    MapperWithReturnType[HF, Out] { type In = In0 }
  def instance[HF, Out <: HList, In0 <: HList](f: In0 => Out): Aux[HF, Out, In0] = 
    new MapperWithReturnType[HF, Out] {
      override type In = In0
      override def apply(t: In0): Out = f(t)
    }

  implicit def hnilMapper[HF <: Poly]: Aux[HF, HNil, HNil] = instance(_ => HNil)

  implicit def hconsMapper[HF <: Poly, InH, InT <: HList, OutH, OutT <: HList](implicit
    hc : poly.Case1.Aux[HF, InH, OutH],
    mt : Aux[HF, OutT, InT]
  ): Aux[HF, OutH :: OutT, InH :: InT] = instance(l => hc(l.head) :: mt(l.tail))
}

implicit final class HListOps[L <: HList](l : L) extends Serializable {
  def mapWithReturnType[Out <: HList](f: Poly)(implicit 
    mapper: MapperWithReturnType.Aux[f.type, Out, L]
  ): Out = mapper(l)
}

val x = ((None: Option[Int]) :: (None: Option[Int]) :: 12 :: HNil)
    .mapWithReturnType[BestBeforeDate](PolyToField)

// val x = (Option.empty[Int] :: Option.empty[Int] :: 12 :: HNil)
//    .mapWithReturnType[BestBeforeDate](PolyToField)

x: BestBeforeDate
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution works well. Any idea why it isn't already included in shapeless?

Comment: @MarkusAppel There are so many different possible type classes... :)